# How to Find Time difference with hours, minutes and seconds (All Results) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, time

How to Find Time difference with all conditions like

if difference only minutes

```
 49 mintus
```

if a difference in Hour

```
 1 hour 20 minutes
```

i am trying

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2018-08-09 10:16:49.000','2018-08-09 11:14:40.000') AS Diff
```

but this is only show in minutes

I have also tried this one

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = '2018-08-09 10:16:49.000',
        @EndTime datetime = '2018-08-09 12:44:05.000'
SELECT CAST(@EndTime - @StartTime as Time) As TimeDiffere
```

output : `02:27:16.0000000`

but I want to `2hr 27mins 16Sec`

Answer (score 3):

If your SQL-server version higher than 2012, you can try to sue [format](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21c3c/3) function.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
 StartTime datetime,
  EndTime datetime
);

insert into t values ('2018-08-09 10:16:49.000','2018-08-09 12:44:05.000')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT format(EndTime - StartTime ,'hh\hr mm\min\s ss\Sec') As TimeDiffere
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21c3c/3/0)**:

```
|       TimeDiffere |
|-------------------|
| 02hr 27mins 16Sec |
```

**NOTE**

Backslash `\`  can escape keyword from the `format` like `hr`,`min`,`s`..., then display it as the original word.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @StartTime datetime = '2018-08-09 10:01:15.000',
        @EndTime datetime = '2018-08-09 12:50:00.000'
SELECT CONCAT((DATEDIFF(second,@StartTime,@EndTime )/60)/60,'hr ',(DATEDIFF(second,@StartTime,@EndTime)/60)%60,'mins ',DATEDIFF(second,@StartTime,@EndTime)%60,'Sec') 
As TimeDiffere
```

Comment: This answer will not return the correct result. This will return 1 hour even though it is only 1 minute: SELECT datediff(hh, '11:59', '12:00')

Comment: you need to use the same `DATEDIFF()` for calculation of all the time components

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartTime  datetime = '2018-08-09 12:16:49.000',
        @EndTime    datetime = '2018-08-09 12:44:05.000'

select  [hour] + [minute] + [second] as TimeDiffere
from    (
            select diff_sec = datediff(second, @StartTime, @EndTime)
        ) t
        cross apply
        (
            select  [hour] = isnull(convert(varchar(10), nullif(diff_sec / 60 / 60, 0)) 
                           + ' hours ', '')
        ) hr
        cross apply
        (
            select  [minute] = isnull(convert(varchar(10), nullif(diff_sec / 60 % 60, 0)) 
                             + ' mintues ', '')
        ) mn
        cross apply
        (
            select  [second] = isnull(convert(varchar(10), nullif(diff_sec % 60, 0)) 
                             + ' seconds', '')
        ) sc

/*  RESULT

27 mintues 16 seconds

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a poor `datetime` functionality to get `hh.mm.ss`, then you can use `apply` :

```
select t.*, concat( (dtdiff / 3600), 'hr ', (dtdiff / 60) % 60, 'mins ', dtdiff % 60, 'sec')
from table t cross apply
     ( values (datediff(second, startdate, enddate)) 
     ) tt(dtdiff);
```